# Getting Multiple Values from User with Prompt then Put them in to the Single Array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist

- Adding element from user until double enter is clicked.

**Function**

```
function PromptCities {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string[]] $city )
    
        write-host "cities ...."
}
```

**Output:**

```
city[0]: ad
city[1]: asd
city[2]: asd
city[3]: asd
city[4]: asd
city[5]:
cities ....
```

I want to make this, without using params() function in Powershell, How can I make it with while,do-while loop and get inputs from user and save them in a array, when in adding process, after first element the next is **double Enter or Empty**, then stop ask the user to adding element..

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `do-until` loop to keep re-prompting the user until an empty input is received:

```
function Take-Input {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$Name
  )

  $index = 0
  $values = @(
    @(
      do {
        ($term = Read-Host "$Name[$(($index++))]")
      } until (-not $term)
    ) |Select-Object -SkipLast 1
  )

  # now you've got yourself an array!
  $values
}
```

Comment: This is ok but not enough for example, in addition I want to show user term[1]: ..., term[2]... "Input value:" instead of I want to show this $variableName[$count]: ....like that

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki I've updated the answer to show how to display the given index

Comment: @R.Jessen, thank u, but it is not enough, ı almost reached my goal, but I want to show parameter name as dynamically... How can I make dynamically to show my variable name?.. For example; If $city -> show as city[0], city[1], if $county[0],country[1} is it possible? .... "term[$(($index++))]" .... in here "term" has to be dynamically whatever variablename is.

Comment: So replace it with a variable :)

Comment: But variable is dynamic, for example Take-Input ($term).... $input = (Take-Input ($citiy)) , so instead of showing "term" it has to be "city" like that important point is here,... Just showing a message will be changed according to the coming variable name

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Alright, updated again. Now you can do `Take-Input -Name City` to get the prompt `City[0]:`, `City[1]:`, etc.

Comment: But this time, -Name City -> City is not a variable it is a value.... Is there a method to catch variable name dynamically? I measn, $City=New-York, Take-Input -Name $City not like that :S it shows this time "New-York[0]..." maybe it sounds stupid but I try to do this